# Selecting rows in pig latin

Tags: apache-pig

I have data that looks like this:

```
(a,b,c)
(a,c,b)
(a,b,d)
```

Is there something like DISTINCT that will produce output like the following?

```
(a,b,c)
(a,b,d)
```

I would like to ignore order and just compare elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.Your best option is to write an UDF that will take each row,sort the fields and return an ordered  string and then use distinct on it.

**PIG**

```
REGISTER ORDER_UDF.jar;
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (a1: chararray, a2: chararray, a3: chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ORDER_UDF.ORDER(CONCAT(CONCAT(a1,a2),a3));
C = DISTINCT B;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE REPLACE($0,'',','); -- Get back the comma separated fields from the concatenated string.
DUMP D;
```

**UDF**

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
  import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

   public class ORDER extends EvalFunc<String>
   {
     public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try{
            char tempArray[] = ((String)input).toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(tempArray);       
            return new String(tempArray);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought worth contemplating, I would suggest to read and convert the data to bag, sort the bag and select distinct data.

**Pig Script :**

```
inp_data = load 'input.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (field1:chararray,field2:chararray,field3:chararray);
req_data = FOREACH inp_data GENERATE TOBAG(field1,field2,field3) AS (b:bag{t:(token:chararray)});
sorted_data = FOREACH req_data {
                sorted = ORDER b BY token;
                GENERATE sorted AS (sorted_bag:bag{t:(token:chararray)}); 
}

req_data_fmt = DISTINCT(FOREACH sorted_data GENERATE BagToString(sorted_bag,','));

DUMP req_data_fmt;
```